# Contained UIViewControllers - should I use .xib or the storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm making an app that will have a VC doing a similar job as a UITabBarController and I'm using

```
[self addChildViewController:theViewController];
// [self addSubview ... etc
```

to put a custom UIViewController's view as a subview of my main (root) VC.

So my question is, which is the correct way to instantiate a VC and not have to build it's UI programatically - from a .xib file, or from a storyboard?

With a xib:

```
UICustomViewController *controller = [[UICustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"customVC" bundle:nil];
```

With a storyboard:

```
UICustomViewController* child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

I believe .xib files are old stuff and storyboards are the way to go, but I also read [this article](http://seanquinlan.com/2012/05/25/creating-a-container.html), which suggests that using a storyboard to do this is a bit hacky. I don't know, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing any major difference in both way , they are same . but in many other angle storyboard is the straight way, there is nothing any hacky

Answer (score -1):

If you want the child view controller to be present when the app opens, you can do it in a storyboard without any code at all. Add a container view to your root vc, and you will automatically get a view controller embedded in it.